# Is possible add native floatingbutton in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I saw two articles that suggest that is possible add native views in a xaml page in Xamarin.Forms. The articles that I saw is https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-views/xaml/#consuming and https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/

I'd like to add a FloatingActionButton just for my Android App (I'm developing for iOS too) using xaml. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: one of the two posts you reference SPECIFICALLY explains how to use a FAB

Comment: But in that example, he's is using C# with shared project. I'm using PCL and I'd like to do it with XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. There is some FAB implementation in Nuget and git.

Also you can implement it by your self, for this you need to create you FAB renderer in droid project(ios project)

Comment: Thanks! I found an implementation using renderer.